# Where to put reusable functions of Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I created a function like e.g. getAllCitiesOfLocations(). This functions delivers me an aggregation of cities. I want to have this function reusable like e.g. for the index function of the ServiceController. Inside the index function, I want to call the function getAllCitiesOfLocations() to fetch the information and later on deliver it to the view.

However, I red, that it is not proper style to call a function from another controller. Furthermore, I red, that I should create a helper class. Unfortunately, when I search for information how to create a helper class, I only find information about creating helper classes for the views. Can you tell me

1.) Where I should put the function, that should be called by different controllers if needed, and

2.) How I can call the function later on when it is not inside the same controller?

```
  public function getAllCitiesOfLocations(){
    $cities = DB::table('locations')
                ->select('city')
                ->groupBy('city')
                ->get();
    return $cities;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use helper class like this

```
 namespace App\Services;

 class Helper {

      public static function getAllCitiesOfLocations(){
           // Code goes here
      }

 }
```

I usually store it inside app/services folder, but you can have it anywhere you like. Then in your controllers, you can access them like this:

```
 App\Services\Helper::getAllCitiesOfLocations();
```

You can also let laravel autoload this class for you by adding it to your aliases array found in `config/app.php`

```
 'Helper' => App\Services\Helper::class
```

Then when calling methods from your Helper class, you simply

```
  Helper::getAllCitiesOfLocations();
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of function would belong in a model, not a controller.  Generally if its dealing with the database, you put things in models.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is have a **Model**. You can then use that Model in **any controller** you want to.

Please read https://requiremind.github.io/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/ to start working in MVC model.